# Rails link_to not downcasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't understand why this code:

```
<%= link_to String.downcase!, String.downcase! %>
```

Produces this HTML:

```
<a href="/String">String</a>
```

I tried downcase with and without "!", no difference.

Comment: works for me. What Rails version are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.0.Op598 [x86_64-linux]